# What is the proper URL syntax to define a location object and a URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, url

I've seen many examples of one or the other, but none with this specific set up. I have a location object currently in my URL that opens a form via jquery:
    http://blah.com/contact.cfm?show_sales

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.search == "?show_sales") {
        $('#sales_form').show();
    };
```

I would also like a parameter to be in the URL:
    http://blah.com/contact.cfm?item=4445555

I've tried combinations of the two, but I don't know the proper syntax to include both. Everything I've tried won't activate the jquery.

So, what's the proper syntax for this URL?

http://blah.com/contact.cfm?show_sales&item=4445555

(this is an example of one that does not work)

Comment: `http://blah.com/contact.cfm?show_sales&item=4445555` is correct for adding multiple key/value pairs to a querystring. Your JavaScript just isn’t parsing that properly. Remove the leading `?` from `location.search`, then split it on `&`.

Comment: You could split `location.search` or use a `RegExp` to isolate query string fields and values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of URL is right. You should make some changes in the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.search.indexOf("?show_sales")!=-1) {
        $('#sales_form').show();
    };
```

`window.location.search` will return `show_sales&item=4445555`

Comment: As I read it, this statement is basically saying "if the index of "?show_sales" is not equal to -1, show the form." Can you explain why or how the -1 index is involved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use split:

```
var url = "http://blah.com/contact.cfm?show_sales&item=4445555";

var query = url.split("?")[1];

var params = query.split("&");

console.log(params); 


// params[0] = "show_sales"
// params[1] = "item=444555" and you can split again
```